# Change input setting in mac keyboard

Tags: macos

In my keyboard when I pressed this key

[image]

Then I get/display  **'§'** (*with shift+key* -> **'±'** ) instead of what  expected.

How can I set it to work properly?

Also after  Googling I found [this site](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Keyboard-Language-of-a-Mac) but this did not help me.

Comment: In the Input Sources tab of system prefs/language & text, make sure the box for British is not checked and only the box for US is checked.  Does this change things?

Comment: That's the exact button as programmed for a mac keyboard. You might find settings in your keyboard preferences to change this manually.

Comment: @TomGewecke- yup...i checked it...US is Checked..:)

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful (assuming British is NOT also checked), and I modified my answer slightly.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your machine thinks the keyboard "type" is English (International) ISO, when it is really English (USA) ANSI.  This article may help:

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html